# Youtube API get share count for video with specified ID

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, share, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to find out a way to get share count for youtube video with for it id. reading Youtube API specification did not give any results.
Can I get share count for video?
On youtube site on video statistics this information is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get it from YouTube Analytics API so far, based on the videoId, I created below a function in Google Apps Script for this data.

```
function videoShareCount(channelId,videoId) {
  var today = new Date();
  var startDate = YouTube.Videos.list('snippet',{id:videoId}).items[0].snippet.publishedAt;
  var todayFormatted = Utilities.formatDate(today, 'UTC', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
  var startDateFormatted = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(startDate), 'UTC', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  var analyticsResponse = YouTubeAnalytics.Reports.query(
    'channel==' + channelId,
    startDateFormatted,
    todayFormatted,
    'shares',
    {
      dimensions: 'video',
      filters: 'video=='+videoId,
    });
  if (analyticsResponse.rows)
    return analyticsResponse.rows[0][1];
  else
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems to be the best approach to use some analytics. Albert, @Surabhil Sergy, thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

There isnt any Youtube APi methods to get the results.

Use social networking API's to get the results for the particular video's URL.

For example : http://youtu.be/g2QdJio6w64 - http://youtu.be/{VIDEO_ID}

After generating this URL,you can use different social networking api's to get count statistics.

For eg:http://www.sharedcount.com/#url=http%3A%2F%2Fyoutu.be%2Fg2QdJio6w64

Answer (score 1):

This is not provided in Data API v3. But this request seems valid, so I'll file a feature request.

Feel free to [file a feature request in public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20%28Enhancement%20Request%29) to get updated on this issue.

Comment: Ok, @IbrahimUlukaya, thanks.
But if there is any other way to get the share count for specified video in youtube?